# NSDate from NSDateComponents

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I am trying to alter the hh, mm, ss component of an NSDate to that of another NSDate - but for some reason, the time gets set to midnight for some reason. I can't figure out why!

Here is the code;

```
+ (NSDate *) fixTime:(NSDate*)fromDate  toDate:(NSDate *) toDate {
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    [cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    [cal setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    NSLog(@"fromDate=<%@>", [fromDate descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]);
    NSLog(@"toDate=  <%@>", [toDate descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]);

    NSDateComponents *fromTimeComponents = [cal components:( NSHourCalendarUnit   | 
                                                             NSMinuteCalendarUnit | 
                                                             NSSecondCalendarUnit   ) fromDate:fromDate];                               
    NSDateComponents *toDateComponents = [cal components:( NSYearCalendarUnit   | 
                                                           NSMonthCalendarUnit  |  
                                                           NSDayCalendarUnit      ) fromDate:toDate];
    NSDateComponents *toTimeComponents = [cal components:( NSHourCalendarUnit   | 
                                                           NSMinuteCalendarUnit | 
                                                           NSSecondCalendarUnit   ) fromDate:toDate];
    [toTimeComponents setHour:[fromTimeComponents hour]];
    [toTimeComponents setMinute:[fromTimeComponents minute]];
    [toTimeComponents setSecond:[fromTimeComponents second]];
    NSLog(@"toDateComponents year = %d", [toDateComponents year]);                                                     
    NSLog(@"toDateComponents mon  = %d", [toDateComponents month]);                                                    
    NSLog(@"toDateComponents day  = %d", [toDateComponents day]);
    NSLog(@"toTimeComponents hour = %d", [toTimeComponents hour]);                                                     
    NSLog(@"toTimeComponents min  = %d", [toTimeComponents minute]);                                                       
    NSLog(@"toTimeComponents sec  = %d", [toTimeComponents second]);

    NSDate *newDate = [cal dateFromComponents:toDateComponents];
    NSLogDebug(@"newDate=<%@>", [newDate descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]);
    return [[newDate retain] autorelease];
}
```

and here is the debug output on the console. Note the values of hour, min, sec components and the final value of newDate:

```
    <Util.m:229> fromDate=<Monday, July 11, 2011 10:35:00 PM Pacific Daylight Time>
    <Util.m:230> toDate=  <Saturday, July 23, 2011 9:35:00 PM Pacific Daylight Time>

    <Util.m:255> toDateComponents year = 2011
    <Util.m:256> toDateComponents mon  = 7
    <Util.m:257> toDateComponents day  = 23
    <Util.m:258> toTimeComponents hour = 22
    <Util.m:259> toTimeComponents min  = 35
    <Util.m:260> toTimeComponents sec  = 0
    <Util.m:266> newDate=<Saturday, July 23, 2011 12:00:00 AM Pacific Daylight Time>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 31):

You are generating the date off `toDateComponents` here,

```
NSDate *newDate = [cal dateFromComponents:toDateComponents];
```

The information in `toDateComponents` is only the date, month and the year. It doesn't have the time details. So you get `12:00:00 AM`. You have stored the time info in `toTimeComponents` but it isn't used. If you want this to work, you will have to add the time info to `toDateComponents` and probably remove the `toTimeComponents` variable completely.

```
[toDateComponents setHour:[fromTimeComponents hour]];
[toDateComponents setMinute:[fromTimeComponents minute]];
[toDateComponents setSecond:[fromTimeComponents second]];
```